# How to use TIMESTAMPDIFF function when the month less or more than 30 days

Tags: jdbc

The below `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function only count for 30 days per month.
How to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function when the month less or more than 30 days?

The start date for `OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE` (1/1/2012)

```
SELECT  
SUPPLIER_CODE, 
TRN_CURRENT_BAL_HOME AS AMT_DUE,
OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) <=30 THEN TRN_CURRENT_BAL_HOME END) AS  0-30 DAYS,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) >=31 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) <=60 THEN TRN_CURRENT_BAL_HOME END) AS 31-60 DAYS,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) >=61 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) <=90 THEN TRN_CURRENT_BAL_HOME END) AS 61-90 DAYS,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01-00.00.00.000000')-TIMESTAMP( OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE))) >90 THEN TRN_CURRENT_BAL_HOME END) AS MORE THAN 90 DAYS
FROM AP_AGING
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the table defination, what is the datatype of `OTHER_VOUCHER_DATE` column in your table. If you are using SQL-Server, why cant you use `DATEDIFF` function

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF is not SQL Server function. Are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB counts the correct number of days per month. Your example does not use the correct syntax and will throw an exception.

An example of how TIMESTAMPDIFF is used is given below. Note the correct use of separators in timestamp strings:

```
CALL TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, TIMESTAMP('2015-03-01 00:00:00.000000'), TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000000'))
```

The example returns 28, which is the number of days between the first day of February and the first day of March.

Comment: the voucher date can not be fixed